# Conditions on diagonal $D$ such that $\det(A^T DA)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix, with $m>n$, such that $A^TA$ is positive definite. Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix such that $A^TDA$ is rank deficient, i.e. $\det(A^TDA)=0$. Can anything be said about the matrix $D$?

A few things that I can immediately observe are:

1) $D$ can not be of the form $a I$, for any $a\ne 0$;

2) The diagonal elements of $D$ cannot be all positive or all negative.

However, it is not clear to me if $D$ can have a only few entries equal to $0$ (but not all), or a few positive and and a few negative (but not all simultaneously), or the combination of these. Is there any systematic way to determine a necessary condition that $D$ has to satisfy in order to respect the determinant condition? Please share some ideas and possible references if any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "a few" I am trying to imply not all, otherwise it is trivial as I mentioned in point 1) in the question. Do you have an example other than the trivial $0$ matrix?

Comment: Of course, $D=0$ is not interesting. Just wanted to say that you did not exclude this in 1), because $a=0$ gives $D=0$.

Comment: I have mentioned that point in the question now, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If the matrix $A$ is $m\times n$, with $m<n$, then $A^TA$ cannot be positive definite, because its rank is at most $m$, so $\det(A^TA)=0$. Probably you meant $m\ge n$.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been $m>n$. I am correcting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as $D$ has at least one zero entry, we can say that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}
\rk(A^TDA) \leq \rk(D) < n
$$
which implies that $\det (A^TDA) = 0$.

---

Suppose that 
$$
D = \pmatrix{D_1 \\&-D_2}
$$
where $D_1$ and $D_2$ have all positive entries.  Conformally break $A$ up into the block matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{A_1\\A_2}
$$
we then have
$$
A^TDA = A_1^TD_1A_1 - A_2^TD_2A_2
$$
If the row spaces of $A_1$ and $A_2$ have a trivial intersection, then this matrix is necessarily invertible.  However, this matrix need not generally be invertible.  For instance, with 
$$
A = \pmatrix{I\\I}, \quad D = \pmatrix{I\\&-I}
$$
we find that $A^TDA = 0$.

---

Note that if $D$ has entries $d_i$ and $A$ has rows $a_i^T$, then we can write
$$
A^TDA = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i \, a_ia_i^T
$$

Comment: Right. Very nice observations. According to the last expansion, then the rank of $A^TDA$ should be equal to the row rank of the submatrix of $A$ with rows with indices corresponding to the nonzero indices of $d_i$'s , right?

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate a bit on the second point where you are breaking the matrix $A$; I can understand the effect of intersection of row spaces, but how does the intersection of the column spaces affect the invertibility of the matrix?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay To your first comment: not necessarily; see how that "catastrophically" fails with the example I gave.  To your second: I should have said row space, not column space; you're right.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks for the answer.